# usage of all cores in numpy einsum

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, performance, optimization

I have code which heavily uses `np.einsum` calls.
I have installed `numpy-intel` in a python virtual environment using:

```
$ pip install mkl
$ pip install intel-numpy
```

`np.show_config()` prints:

```
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/sat_bot/base/conda-bld/numpy_and_dev_1643279478844/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_p/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/sat_bot/base/conda-bld/numpy_and_dev_1643279478844/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_p/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/sat_bot/base/conda-bld/numpy_and_dev_1643279478844/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_p/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/sat_bot/base/conda-bld/numpy_and_dev_1643279478844/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_p/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/sat_bot/base/conda-bld/numpy_and_dev_1643279478844/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_p/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/sat_bot/base/conda-bld/numpy_and_dev_1643279478844/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_p/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/sat_bot/base/conda-bld/numpy_and_dev_1643279478844/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_p/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/sat_bot/base/conda-bld/numpy_and_dev_1643279478844/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_p/include']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
    not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
```

I have an Intel chip with 16 logical processors (8 cores) in 1 socket.
I want to make sure that the python code's np calls use all the cores on my machine.
What I have tried:

- inside  the WSL I use to run the python scripts, I wrote `export MKL_NUM_THREADS=8` then ran my script normally as `python script.py`.
- inside the `script.py`, before importing `numpy` I wrote:

  import os
  os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = '8' # or 16

None of these trials resulted in a **visible** usage of all the cores when I monitor them in the terminal using `htop`.

There is always a core at 100% utilization, and from time to time (when inside a `np.einsum` call) some other cores (it seems randomly selected from the set not including the constant 100% utilization one - two or three usually) just light to 3% utilization for a few seconds or so, then drop to 0% utilization again.

Does anyone have any idea if this a normal behavior, or is it me who is doing something wrong?

Thank you!

**EDIT TO INCLUDE THE ACTUAL `np.einsum` CALLS (MWE)**

```
N_thetas = 20
N_rs = 600
N_phis = 18

Legendre_matr = np.random.rand(N_thetas,  2*N_thetas-1,  N_thetas)
after_first_int = np.random.rand(N_rs - 1, 2*N_thetas - 1, N_thetas)
eigenvectors_memory = np.random.rand(N_rs - 1, N_rs - 1, N_thetas)
normaliz = np.random.rand(N_rs - 1, )
Cilmoft = np.random.rand(2*N_thetas-1, N_rs-1, N_thetas)
Psi_m = np.random.rand( 2*N_thetas - 1,    N_rs - 1,    gl.N_thetas )
arange_for_m_values = np.arange(-N_thetas+1, N_thetas)
phis = np.linspace(0.0, 2*np.pi, N_phis)    

after_second_int = np.einsum('ijk,rjk->rij', Legendre_matr, after_first_int, optimize=True)


Psi_lm = np.einsum('jkl,j,mkl->jml', eigenvectors_memory, normaliz , Cilmoft, optimize=True) 

Psi_on_grid_from_Cilmoft = np.einsum('xjk,xn->jkn',   Psi_m,  np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)), optimize=True )
```

Comment: Well, It would be nice if you show us the actual einsum calls. In general, The first thing to try is to use blas operations (matmul, tensordot or dot), also try  using```optimize=True``` flag and see if it works (some times it dispatches to blas), There is also multithreaded version of einsum: https://pypi.org/project/einsumt/

Comment: @Murali, thank you. I will set the ``optimize=True`` keyword and see what happens. I did download and use the ``einsumt`` library, but it crashed my code with a ``Killed`` message, in contrast to the plain ``np.einsum()`` calls which work (Indeed, I am very close to the maximum RAM memory of my computer, and with my limited knowledge I suspect that ``einsumt`` creates temporary arrays which saturate the RAM)

Comment: `einsum` is a complicated function.  In some cases it reduces the problem to a call to `matmul`, which will result in using BLAS etc.  But for other combinations of indices it does the calculation in-house.  I don't think the `optimize` parameter affects this.  It has more effect when working with 3 or more arguments, where evaluation order can make a difference.

Comment: @hpaulj, thank you. only one of my calls to ``einsum`` has three arguments, the others have 2 arguments. In principle, can any ``np.einsum`` be converted to ``np`` functions which use BLAS (so that I can use all my 16 cores, and in principle, go to a HPC cluster)?

Comment: @hpaulj I think einsum only dispatches to blas when you set ```optimize = True```. So I think it matters even for 2  arguments. Best example is a simple matrix multiplication.

Comment: @velenos14 As I mentioned earlier, people can only help if you provide the actual einsum call. It is difficulty to tell anything without seeing the code.

Comment: please see the updated answer, now it shall work

Comment: @velenos14 Why not break the arrays into smaller chunks and use ```einsumt```  for first two einsums?

Comment: @Murali, this is exactly what I was thinking about with a pen and paper, but a little bit different: "I can benefit from 128 cores. Would it be a good idea to split the array into 128 chunks and perform 1core-operations (np.einsum) on each chunk?"

Comment: @velenos14 Why to do it your self again? I would simple write a loop, break in into small chunks( so that you don't run into memory issues) and let einsumt take care of the thread business.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [3]: Legendre_matr.shape, after_first_int.shape
Out[3]: ((20, 39, 20), (599, 39, 20))
```

Your first `einsum`:

```
In [4]: np.einsum('ijk,rjk->rij', Legendre_matr, after_first_int).shape
Out[4]: (599, 20, 39)
```

time  - optimize doesn't help (it's a bit slower because of the extra time taking to evaluate a path):

```
In [5]: timeit np.einsum('ijk,rjk->rij', Legendre_matr, after_first_int)
14.1 ms ± 13.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [6]: timeit np.einsum('ijk,rjk->rij', Legendre_matr, after_first_int, optimize=True)
14.3 ms ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

My reading of the `optimize` parameter matters when there are more than 2 arguments, and the order of evaluation matters.  There's nothing in the docs about using BLAS or not.

```
In [9]: print(np.einsum_path('ijk,rjk->rij', Legendre_matr, after_first_int)[1])
  Complete contraction:  ijk,rjk->rij
         Naive scaling:  4
     Optimized scaling:  4
      Naive FLOP count:  1.869e+07
  Optimized FLOP count:  1.869e+07
   Theoretical speedup:  1.000
  Largest intermediate:  4.672e+05 elements
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
scaling                  current                                remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4                rjk,ijk->rij                                rij->rij
```

### `matmul`

By adding some dimensions, I can do the same thing with `matmul`:

```
In [19]: after_first_int[:,None,:,None].shape,Legendre_matr[None,:,:,:,None].shape
Out[19]: ((599, 1, 39, 1, 20), (1, 20, 39, 20, 1))
In [21]: (after_first_int[:,None,:,None]@Legendre_matr[None,:,:,:,None]).squeeze().shape
Out[21]: (599, 20, 39)
```

time is essentially the same:

```
In [22]: timeit (after_first_int[:,None,:,None]@Legendre_matr[None,:,:,:,None]).squeeze().shape
14.6 ms ± 16.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Values match as well as shape:

```
In [27]: x1=np.einsum('ijk,rjk->rij', Legendre_matr, after_first_int)
In [28]: x2=(after_first_int[:,None,:,None]@Legendre_matr[None,:,:,:,None]).squeeze()
In [29]: np.allclose(x1,x2)
Out[29]: True
```

I'm not a position to evaluate the use of cores (only 2 cores).

### third einsum

This one has the sum-of-products first. That requires a transpose to use matmul:

```
In [56]: x1 = np.einsum('xjk,xn->jkn',   Psi_m,  np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)))
    ...: 
In [57]: x2=(Psi_m.transpose(1,2,0)@np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)))
In [58]: np.allclose(x1,x2)
Out[58]: True
```

timings:

```
In [59]: timeit x2=(Psi_m.transpose(1,2,0)@np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)))
13.6 ms ± 16.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [60]: timeit np.einsum('xjk,xn->jkn',   Psi_m,  np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)
    ...: ), optimize=True)
9.37 ms ± 17.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [61]: timeit np.einsum('xjk,xn->jkn',   Psi_m,  np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)
    ...: ), optimize=False)
133 ms ± 3.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Interesting that the True `einsum` case is faster than the matmul.  The `einsum` False case is significantly slower, indicating a much slower evaluate route (not using BLAS at all).  The `einsum_path` tells us nothing since there are only two arguments.

Years ago I contributed a patch to `einsum`, enabling correct use of the `ellipsis`.  At that time all calculations went through `nditer` in `cython` code.  Since then it has gone through several patches, adding for example the `optimize` and some sort of link to `matmul`.  The default value for `optimize` has flip-flopped a few times.

Timings such as what I've done give us some idea of what's happening, but it's not the same as actually studying the code (a mix of python and compiled).

Comment: Well, It doesn't make difference because it cannot be dispatched to blas (in first two cases) and as you said, there is nothing to do with the order. but in the third einsum, it clearly matters (when optimize=True as it dispatches to blas).

Comment: alright, so it seems that only the third einsum call (from my MWE) actually benefits from all the cores of the machine. By making the calculations as you did (i.e. using np.matmul and shape manipulation), I would use all the cores, right? (I am not entirely sure, but I knew that ``np.matmul`` uses BLAS)

Comment: The second one, with 3 terms, shows a modest `path` related speedup.  The thind shows a big improvement with `optimize=True`, though there isn't a path related difference (only two arguments).  The sum-of-products dimension, `x` is first; `optimize` may give it "permission" to move that into a `matmul` position.

Comment: "Interesting that the True einsum case is faster than the matmul" is Not true. You are not using the full potential of BLAS. It is slower because you write it as batched matmul. Instread write it in one matmul  Try this ```(np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)).T @ Psi_m.reshape(Psi_m.shape[0],-1)).reshape(-1,Psi_m.shape[1],Psi_m.shape[2]).transpose(1,2,0)```. The beauty is einsum does this for you.

Comment: ```einsum_path``` does not give you full information about this. To get clear info of what is going on, I would suggest you to look into https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.  where some of its parts are implemented in einsum

Answer (score 2):

As suggested earlier, one way is to break it into chucks and use einsumt.
But I still feel that you can dispatch into multiple dot products and squeeze some more performance using Numba too.

```
import numpy as np

N_thetas = 20
N_rs = 600
N_phis = 18

Legendre_matr = np.random.rand(N_thetas,  2*N_thetas-1,  N_thetas)
after_first_int = np.random.rand(N_rs - 1, 2*N_thetas - 1, N_thetas)
eigenvectors_memory = np.random.rand(N_rs - 1, N_rs - 1, N_thetas)
normaliz = np.random.rand(N_rs - 1, )
Cilmoft = np.random.rand(2*N_thetas-1, N_rs-1, N_thetas)
Psi_m = np.random.rand( 2*N_thetas - 1,    N_rs - 1,    N_thetas )
arange_for_m_values = np.arange(-N_thetas+1, N_thetas)
phis = np.linspace(0.0, 2*np.pi, N_phis)
```

**1st einsum**:

```
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True, cache=True, nogil=True)
def first_einsum(a,b):
    c= np.zeros((b.shape[0],a.shape[0],a.shape[1]))
    for r in prange(b.shape[0]):
        for i in prange(a.shape[0]):
            for j in prange(a.shape[1]):
                c[r,i,j] = np.dot(a[i,j,:],b[r,j,:])
    return c

%timeit np.einsum('ijk,rjk->rij', Legendre_matr, after_first_int, optimize=True)
# 30 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit first_einsum(Legendre_matr, after_first_int)
# 11.2 ms ± 544 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Clearly I could squeeze some perfomance out of it

**2nd einsum**:

You can write second einsum in terms off first_einsum function

```
def second_einsum(a,b,c):
    temp_arr = np.einsum('jkl,j->jlk',a,b) # 'jkl,j->jlk'
    return first_einsum(np.ascontiguousarray(c.transpose(0,2,1)),temp_arr) # 'mlk,jlk->jml'
   
%timeit np.einsum('jkl,j,mkl->jml', eigenvectors_memory, normaliz , Cilmoft, optimize=True)
# 676 ms ± 13.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit second_einsum(eigenvectors_memory, normaliz , Cilmoft)
# 287 ms ± 10.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**3rd einsum**

When `optimize=True` it is dispatching to blas so it is already well optimized.

```
np.einsum('xjk,xn->jkn',   Psi_m,  np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)), optimize=True )
%timeit np.einsum('xjk,xn->jkn',   Psi_m,  np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)), optimize=True )

# 16.3 ms ± 754 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

To disprove @hpaulj statement that BLAS is slower than einsu,. you also write the above einsum in matrix multiplications

```
(np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)).T @ Psi_m.reshape(Psi_m.shape[0],-1)).reshape(-1,Psi_m.shape[1],Psi_m.shape[2]).transpose(1,2,0)

%timeit (np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)).T @ Psi_m.reshape(Psi_m.shape[0],-1)).reshape(-1,Psi_m.shape[1],Psi_m.shape[2]).transpose(1,2,0)

# 15.1 ms ± 151 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Clearly BLAS WINS by a little margin due to overhead of `einsum` when `optimize=True`

How do I know if `einsum` dispatches to BLAS when `optimize=True`?

```
In [37]: np.einsum_path('xjk,xn->jkn',   Psi_m,  np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)))
Out[37]:
(['einsum_path', (0, 1)],
 '  Complete contraction:  xjk,xn->jkn\n         Naive scaling:  4\n     Optimized scaling:  4\n      Naive FLOP count:  1.682e+07\n  Optimized FLOP count:  1.682e+07\n   Theoretical speedup:  1.000\n  Largest intermediate:  2.156e+05 elements\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\nscaling                  current                                remaining\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n   4                 xn,xjk->jkn                                 jkn->jkn')

In [38]: np.einsum_path('xjk,xn->jkn',   Psi_m,  np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)),optimize=True)
Out[38]:
(['einsum_path', (0, 1)],
 '  Complete contraction:  xjk,xn->jkn\n         Naive scaling:  4\n     Optimized scaling:  4\n      Naive FLOP count:  1.682e+07\n  Optimized FLOP count:  1.682e+07\n   Theoretical speedup:  1.000\n  Largest intermediate:  2.156e+05 elements\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\nscaling                  current                                remaining\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n   4                 xn,xjk->jkn                                 jkn->jkn')
```

Clearly `einsum_path` doesn't give you any information whether it is calling BLAS.

The evaluation order in einsum is mostly taken from the `opt_einsum` library. This can tell if einsum is actually using BLAS

```
In [45]: import opt_einsum as oe

In [46]: path_info = oe.contract_path('xjk,xn->jkn',   Psi_m,  np.exp(1j * np.outer(arange_for_m_values, phis)))

In [47]: print(path_info)
([(0, 1)],   Complete contraction:  xjk,xn->jkn
         Naive scaling:  4
     Optimized scaling:  4
      Naive FLOP count:  1.682e+7
  Optimized FLOP count:  1.682e+7
   Theoretical speedup:  1.000e+0
  Largest intermediate:  2.156e+5 elements
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
scaling        BLAS                current                             remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4           GEMM            xn,xjk->jkn                              jkn->jkn)
```

And you see a gemm call, It is very likely that einsum does the same as the implementation is more or less borrowed from opt_einsum

Comment: Note: The second einsum function creates temporary arrays so it is bit memory expensive

Comment: I didn't claim that `einsum` was faster than BLAS (in general).  It was faster than that particular `matmul` call.  What you've shown is that `matmul` times can vary with the mix of dimensions, with the fastest being "pure" 2d matrix multiplication.  `np.dot` could be used in such a case with similar times.  `matmul/@` was added primarily to improve "batched" multiplications.